# Global references in php

Tags: php, variables, reference, global

I read this article on php.net:

"When you declare a variable as `global $var` you are in fact creating reference to a global variable. That means, this is the same as:

```
<?php
$var =& $GLOBALS["var"];
?>
```

This also means that unsetting `$var` won't unset the global variable."

What I understand from this is that when you declare a variable as `global $var`, you set another name for the variable name $GLOBALS["var"]. So if you echo one or another, you get the same thing. But I find the last sentence confusing, since the following snippet outputs 'red':

```
$GLOBALS['var']='blue';
global $var;  //This is supposed to be equivalent to $var=& $GLOBALS["var"];
//echo $var,'<br/>';
$var='red';
echo $GLOBALS['var']; //I would expect this to output 'blue', instead of 'red'
```

I was expecting the output to be 'blue' since it states that unsetting `$var` won't unset the global variable. Where're the mistake?

If I do `unset($var)`, how should I check that the global variable was not unset?

Comment: when you declare `$var` as a global, any changes locally are reflected globally, even from inside a function.

Comment: Can you give the whole piece of code together with comments on what your actual output was? How does the current output differ from your expectation?

Comment: Yes. And the answer is: You are writing "red" into $var, and because that is a reference to the $GLOBALS (created by "global $var"), it overwrites the value there - just like references work.

Comment: @Sven Oh, I can modify the value using either of the two 'names'. Now it's clear. (References are means to access the same variable content by different name.)

Answer (score 2):

```
$var='red';
```

It's not unsetting, it's assigment. Assigment affects to global variable.

> This also means that unsetting $var won't unset the global variable.

It's about using `unset` function. `unset($var)` removes variable from current scope, but global variable is still there.

Comment: Indeed. I did not know what unset means. I thought it means changing its value. I also misunderstood what a reference means. But the part where the variable is still there it's still unclear. How can I access it?

Comment: @TanatosDaniel , after unseting $var?

Comment: @TanatosDaniel , write `global $var` one more time.

Comment: Added global $var; echo $var; But there's no output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that you missed that minor detail, the `&`. What that does, is it says you want the [original reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) and not a copy of the variable.

```
function test() {
    $var = $GLOBALS['x'];
    $var2 = &$GLOBALS['x'];
    echo $GLOBALS['x'] . "\n";
    $var2 = 'red';
    echo $var . "\n" . $GLOBALS['x'];

}

$x = 'blue';
test();
```

This outputs

```
blue
red
```

You'll note that `$var` was assigned to global version, but what happened was PHP only *copied* `$x`. With `$var2`, we told PHP that we wanted the reference, or, in other words, the actual address of `$x`. This makes a huge difference because `$var` is only a copy. Changing it only changes the copy. Note in my example that I changed the value of `$x`, but only `$var2` reflected that change. `$var` still had what `$x` was at the beginning.

Comment: Please forgive me, but I'm still not getting it.

Comment: Me neither. Perhaps this means that with `$var =& $GLOBALS["var"];` You're not setting `$var`, you're creating a pointer to `$GLOBALS["var"]`

Comment: Sorry, took me a min to get an example typed up. Hopefully that answers it